# Weird situation Crashes on Mapview in storyboard when Add child controller or Present (Sample code added)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have view Controller in storyboard with mapview only.

```
class MapVC: UIViewController {
    class func viewController () -> MapVC {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Dashboard", bundle: nil)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapVC") as! MapVC
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

I have simple Login screen

On Login button action  I call this method

```
 private func addChildVC (_ vc:UIViewController) {
        self.removeAllChild()
        self.addChild(vc)
        vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParent: self)
        self.currentCenterViewController = vc

  }
```

With

```
MapVC.viewController()
```

App Crashes on

```
vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds
```

Weird is if I am debugging like debugger attached and when I press on Login App not crashing but when Debugger not attached on launch and then I start app in simulator then attach process and when I press login button App crashes

Present view controller is also not working crashes the app

**If I remove Mapview from storyboard app is working fine in both case**

When I check `vc.isViewLoaded` is returning `false`

tried  loadViewIfRequired() 
Clean Derived Data, Clean project restart xcode.
Verify that I have added correct Identifers

[image]

I am not able to understand the reason Please help

**EDIT**

Sample App

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-otaZhhhDEH4p29CgQP7xZSX9tizceq8

Steps to reproduce

1) Run in any simulator of ios 12 
2) Press stop from xcode 
3) From simulator launch the app 
4) Press button

**EDIT2**

issue video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z9C3Re_oVYkRncnE22xRoef2Kv2WyzId/view

File a bug https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=46774084

[image]

Comment: Can you share project if this is demo app ?

Comment: @MayurKarmur yes Please give me moment

Comment: And also tell me which XCode you are using.

Comment: @MayurKarmur using xcode10 , swift 4.2 . added sample project

Comment: Thanks for link, but project haven't storyboard extension, instead it looks as xml.

Comment: @MayurKarmur Could  you please try https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-otaZhhhDEH4p29CgQP7xZSX9tizceq8

Comment: your project runs without any problems

Comment: @Sh_Khan Please stop debugging and just launch it from simulator

Comment: the map shows in simulator

Comment: @Sh_Khan Can I share Video ?

Comment: look temporarily in edit .........

Comment: @Sh_Khan Please have a look https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z9C3Re_oVYkRncnE22xRoef2Kv2WyzId

Comment: @Sh_Khan I have added video in question any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what actually issue and why your app crash. But I have found solution.
Add **MapKit.framework** in **Link Binary With Libraries** will fix you issue.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: in view controller just adding `import MapKit`  also solves the issue Thanks :)\

Comment: Still There is Question left why it is working when debugger attached ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, You can raise this issue as new question.

Comment: Found the reason !! added in my answer

Answer (score 2):

I have found the actual reason behind it.

It is because of **view debugger framework**

Here is reply from apple developer team

> Engineering has provided the following information regarding this issue:
>
> The sample project provided is not configured correctly.
>
> The application is using the MapKit framework, but has not been configured to link with MapKit. When run using the debugger, MapKit is pulled in because it’s linked by the view debugger framework.
>
> When the app is launched from the simulator, without the view debugger, MapKit will not be loaded into the runtime as the app has not specified this as a dependency and therefor it crashes.
>
> Updating your sample project to link MapKit solves the issue with the application crashing.